# Filling NA values with repetition of the leftmost non-NA value in zoo

Tags: r, null, zoo

How to fill NA values with repetition of the leftmost non-NA value in `zoo`?

In zoo pdf guide we have the function `na.fill` which performs this task. My question is how to say the function to take the leftmost non-NA value?

Below a little example

```
> z <- zoo(c(NA, 2, NA, 1, 4, 5, 2, NA))
> z
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
NA  2 NA  1  4  5  2 NA 
> na.fill(z, "extend")
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
2.0 2.0 1.5 1.0 4.0 5.0 2.0 2.0 
> na.fill(z, c("extend", NA))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 2  2 NA  1  4  5  2  2
```

The result I want is the following:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 NA  2 2  1  4  5  2  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(c(NA, 2, NA, 1, 4, 5, 2, NA))
na.locf(z, na.rm = FALSE)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
#NA  2  2  1  4  5  2  2
```

Comment: FWIW, if you don't have a `zoo` object, you can do tricks like `rle(is.na(myvector))` and crunch the resulting info.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: you can use `na.locf` on a plain vector.  zoo provides a `na.locf.default` method.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  Thanks for the info.  I need to learn more about `zoo` .